Transit Visa Requirement with a self-transfer in Paris
I am a Canadian Permanent Resident and have booked flights from Canada to Delhi with a self-transfer in Paris. My itinerary consists of two separate tickets: one with WestJet from Calgary to Paris and another with Air India from Paris to Delhi.
Being an Indian Passport holder, with a Canadian Permanent resident status, do I have to get an Airport transit visa in this case?
I do not have any check-in baggage for this trip, so I won't need to collect any luggage at Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport.
I would like to confirm whether I require a Transit Visa for Paris. Based on the information available on the website, it seems that Canadian Permanent Residents are exempt from needing a Transit Visa. However, I am still uncertain and would appreciate any views.

The problem is that for the first airline, your final destination is Paris, not Delhi.
In that case, they will want to see paperwork showing you can enter France, not just do an airside transit. That means a "full" Schengen visa (type C), not just an ATV (which you would indeed not need being a Canadian PR).
Whether they will accept the fact that you have a connection which allows you to stay airside and thus not require a visa is highly variable, and depends a lot on the airline and often on the individual agent. The cheaper the airline, the less likely it is. You should ask Westjet in advance if they would allow it, ideally with confirmation in writing.
Of course you can stay airside only if:

You don't have hold luggage (including anything "checked at the gate" due to size/weight/number or lack of space)
You can actually get your boarding pass for the second flight without having to go to a check-in desk (ideally online/mobile).


Thanks for the reply. I had checked at the Westjet counter at the Airport and they seemed ok with this arrangement but like you said, it is highly variable and depends on person to person. I will try to get something in writing from Westjet. Thanks
